# condition in entry box in tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have written a script in python 3.4 and i want to put a if-else condition in entry box of tkinter. Is this possible?

Note: Currently the code is not working correctly. Please let me know, what i have written in my code is possible or not ?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a = ""
b = "hello"

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.insert(0, if(len(a) == 0) b else a)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
e.insert(0, b if not a else a)
```

Also, I suggest you don't check for empty strings like that - the most idiomatic way (in your case) would be:

```
if not a
```

You can read more about conditional expressions [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Comment: thanks. but can you please tell me why you put the if block statement before writing if block ?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: that's what the syntax is. You can find out more about it in the link I posted in my updated answer.